# Word order in Je-desto phrases

Tags: conjunction, subordinate-clause

> "Je mehr Kleidung man erwirbt, desto mehr Muell produziert man."

I would like to know, why does "produziert" not go to the end in the Nebensatz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second part is the Hauptsatz, while the "Je ..." part is the Nebensatz in a "Je ... , desto ..." sentence.

In the main clause here, the first position is "desto mehr Müll" (accusative object), the second position is the verb "produziert", and the last position is the subject "man". So the verb is in second position, as it should be in a Hauptsatz. The object comes first here because in a "Je ..., desto ..." sentence the "desto" needs to come first in the Hauptsatz, and "desto" happens to refer to the object "mehr Müll" here.

Comment: What type of grammatical object is desto?

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Dictionaries say it's a *conjunction*, it connects the clause to its context. It is quite a special one though because of its strong binding to the comparative that always goes with it.